# Dynamic Dropdown Issues

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a dynamic dropdown list that i followed on this link [Dynamic Drop Down](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/create-dynamic-drop-down-list/)

But to my results i got this code but something is wrong???
nothing happens it stays blank no error or anything in the console???

### Html Code

```
<div id="Dropdown_box">
    <p style="background-color:#456;margin-top:-10px;margin-left:10px;display:inline-block;padding:10px;">Please Select The DropDown Options</p> 
    <p></p>

    <div id="DropDown_List_Main" name="DropDown_List_Main">
    <select Id="DropDown_List_Main" onchange="javascript: dropdown_1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Visitor">Visitor</option>
        <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
        <option value="Company">Company</option>
        <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="DropDown_List_Main" name="DropDown_List_Main">
    <script type="text/Javascript" language="Javascript">
document.write('<select name="DropDown_List" id="DropDown_List" ><option value="">Please Select</option></select>')
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <p>Please Enable Javascript</p>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

### Javascript Code

```
function DropDown_1(listindex) {
    document.getElementById('DropDown_List').length = 0;
    switch(listindex){
        case "Visitor":
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Question","Question");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Request","Request");
            break;

        case "Customer":
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Question","Question");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Request","Request");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Reciept","Reciept");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[4]=new Option("Complaint","Complaint");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[5]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
            break;

        case "Company":
           document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
           document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Request","Request");
           document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Reciept","Reciept");
           document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Complaint","Complaint");
           document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[4]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
           document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[5]=new Option("Delivery","Delivery");
           break;

        case "Supplier":
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Request","Request");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Reciept","Reciept");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Complaint","Complaint");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[4]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
            document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[5]=new Option("Delivery","Delivery");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please all help Would be great! 
Please dont refer me to JQuery am new or more or less new to javascript 
I try to use anything other than javascript but there is only PHP and mysql database methode obv this is part of a form the second dropdown needs codes to unhide or create the fill in fields corresponding the 1st dropdown list.

Any help on that would also be great please Otherwise could there be any other programing i could use other than JQuery?

Comment: Just an assumption: you want to call `dropdown_1()` in your onchange attribute, but your method is called `DropDown_1()`. It's case-sensitive

Comment: you have at least 3 elements with id or name of "DropDown_List_Main" and none with "DropDown_List" which is what your code is trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is function name. Javascript is **case sensitive**.It should be dropdown_1 as you mentioned in the onchange.

```js
function dropdown_1(listindex) {
    document.getElementById('DropDown_List').length = 0;
switch(listindex){
    case "Visitor":
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Question","Question");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Request","Request");
break;

    case "Customer":
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Question","Question");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Request","Request");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Reciept","Reciept");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[4]=new Option("Complaint","Complaint");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[5]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
break;

case "Company":
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Request","Request");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Reciept","Reciept");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Complaint","Complaint");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[4]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[5]=new Option("Delivery","Delivery");
break;

case "Supplier":
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[0]=new Option("Please Select","");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[1]=new Option("Request","Request");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[2]=new Option("Reciept","Reciept");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[3]=new Option("Complaint","Complaint");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[4]=new Option("Compliment","Compliment");
document.getElementById("DropDown_List").options[5]=new Option("Delivery","Delivery");
break;

}

document.getElementById('DropDown_List').style.display='';
return true;
}
```

```html
 <div id="Dropdown_box">
<p style="background-color:#456;margin-top:-10px;margin-left:10px;display:inline-block;padding:10px;">Please Select The DropDown Options</p> 
<p></p>

<div id="DropDown_List_Main" name="DropDown_List_Main">
<select Id="DropDown_List_Main" onchange="javascript: dropdown_1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Visitor">Visitor</option>
    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
    <option value="Company">Company</option>
    <option value="Supplier">Supplier</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="DropDown_List_Main" name="DropDown_List_Main">
<script type="text/Javascript" language="Javascript">
document.write('<select name="DropDown_List" id="DropDown_List" style="display:none;"><option value="">Please Select</option></select>')
</script>
<noscript>
<p>Please Enable Javascript</p>
</noscript>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check this? @Nathan Gr

Comment: Yes seriously such a small error and im sitting here trying to figure out what i did wrong lol thanks! i feel like an idiot lol Really it worked!

Comment: How do i Like or save as closed coz its fixed thanks for the help :)

Comment: If i were to hid that second drop down until the first one is selected wld i just change the display to none? I mean like the document.write how do i activate the script only once the first dropdown is selected i think an if function but that wld start right a way? how do i activate only when the first dropdown is selecteed?

Comment: glad to help...@Nathan Gr

Comment: you want to hide the second dropdown until value trigger?

Comment: yes after they selected something from the first dropdown

Comment: i updated the code as you asked check now..@Nathan Gr

Comment: Thanks :) it really helped! thanks alot i think im gonna stop asking coz its gonna keep going on haha thanks! it worked great... If it ever gets finished and they decide to make it live than i will post a link on my profile :)